# Computational complexity to compute an IIS

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, feasible-points, irreducible-infeasible-subset, computational-complexity

How hard is it to compute an irreducible infeasible subset (IIS) for a linear program? What about an integer program (*e.g.*, removing the integrality constraint on a single variable may be enough to render the problem feasible, but this seems rather different than the LP case)?

Finally, how hard is it to compute the *minimum* number of constraints that must be removed to render an LP (and/or IP) feasible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finding a minimum-cardinality MIS for a linear program is an NP-hard problem in general, see [Edoardo Amaldi, Marc E. Pfetsch, and Leslie E. Trotter Jr. On the maximum feasible subsystem problem, IISs and IIS-hypergraphs. Mathematical Programming, 95(3):533–554, 2003](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10107-002-0363-5). For this reason, commercial solvers such as CPLEX use heuristics to identify small IIS which are not necessarily of minimum cardinality. Notice that for a given LP, there may be multiple overlapping IISs. To achieve feasibility, one must delete at least one inequality from each IIS. The aforementioned paper therefore defines Min IIS Covers.